# How to Add QListView/QListWidget to QGraphicsScene in Qt?

Tags: qt

How to Add QListView/QListWidget to QGraphicsScene and add Widgets to ListView 
When i Try to add QLisView to QGraphicsScene mouse scroll affects goes from Scene.
I want to add QPushButtons as ListView Items in QgraphicsScene with mouse scroll affect.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you try to add `QListView` to `QGraphicsScene`? Can you post some code?

Comment: @ayoy : That's my question how to add QLsiview to qGraphicsScene.I have still not got any idea how to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

What about `QGraphicsProxyWidget`?

```
QListView *listView = new QListView;
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene.addWidget(listView);
```

Then (or before that) you can populate the list with anything you want. `QPushButton` can be added to the list using `setIndexWidget()`. Also you might rethink the whole idea of having a `QListView`, and give it a try with `QScrollArea` and a linear layout containing buttons. That would require a bit more logic to organize items within the scroll area, but it should be more lightweight that `QListView` with custom widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I second the answer above: ProxyWidget is the answer.

Here is my working code,
Header:

```
class CenterScreen{
private:
    QListWidget* nameListWidget;
    QGraphicsProxyWidget* nameProxyWidget;
...
```

C++ source:

```
void CenterScreen::addListView()
{
    QGraphicsScene* scene = ui.centerGraphicsView->scene();
    nameListWidget = new QListWidget();
    nameProxyWidget = scene->addWidget(nameListWidget);
...
    nameProxyWidget->hide();    // you can control your widget as you like
```